# VBA using Concat function

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I have a workbook with 2 sheets. In sheet 2 (B2), I want to use Concat function to combine A2 (which is a mobile number) from Sheet one and preferably use current Month and Year automatically as second part of the Concat so it would give an answer like 01234567910 - Nov23 or if that is not possible a message box to manually enter date.

I can get the first part to work but not the second.

Comment: `=Sheet1!A2&" - "&TEXT(TODAY(),"Mmmyy")`. If you want VBA, then use `Format`.

Answer (score 0):

- `Date` returns the current system date.
- `Format` returns date in the desired format.
- `&` is a string concat operator.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("B2").Value = .Range("A2").Value & Format(Date, " - MMMyy")
    End With
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Date function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008925)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)